# How to run bundle install with a Dockerfile file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I want to use docker to deploy a rails application.
I followed the official tutorial to do:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/

But it seems I am not lucky.

My Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.2.2

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential

# for mysql
RUN apt-get install -y mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev

# for a JS runtime
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

ENV APP_HOME /myapp
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

ADD Gemfile $APP_HOME/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock $APP_HOME/Gemfile.lock

RUN bundle install

ADD . $APP_HOME
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
db:
  image: mysql
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
web:
  build: .
  command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
  volumes:
    - .:/myapp
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  links:
    - db
```

After I run `docker-compose build`, it shows:

```
...
Fetching git://github.com/guard/guard-test.git
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:94:in `[]': invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError)
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:94:in `strip_leading_spaces'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:99:in `word_wrap'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:85:in `tell_me'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:31:in `error'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:12:in `rescue in with_friendly_errors'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:7:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/bin/bundle:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bundle/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bundle/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c bundle install' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Can you add an `export LANG=C.UTF-8` (as in https://github.com/koken/docker-koken-lemp/blob/master/Dockerfile#L12, after http://stackoverflow.com/a/14840029/6309)

Comment: @VonC Thank you. You are right. After I added that. It works! Can you write it down as an answer? I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at a similar error in "[bundle install error “invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError)”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14840029/6309)", one option is to ad to the Dockerfile:

```
export LANG=C.UTF-8
```

See [this Dockerfile](https://github.com/koken/docker-koken-lemp/blob/aa6ebe5b5959e0f32562ce965286785453218efb/Dockerfile#L12) for instance.

```
# Install required packages
# LANG=C.UTF-8 line is needed for ondrej/php5 repository
RUN \
    export LANG=C.UTF-8 && \
    ...
```

Comment: But that is not enough. The new problem is: `sidekiq_1 | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/source/git/git_proxy.rb:155:in `allowed_in_path': The git source git://github.com/guard/guard-test.git is not yet checked out. Please run `bundle install` before trying to start your application (Bundler::GitError)`.

Comment: @scho can you make an new question with your Dockerfile and the error message?

Comment: Yes. I asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33564984/how-to-install-guard-test-with-docker