# How to install guard-test with docker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I am using rails, docker.

In my old application, there are some old methods and gems.

In my Gemfile, I added
group :development, :test do
  gem 'guard-test', github: 'guard/guard-test'
end

Then run `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up`, the error message is:

```
sidekiq_1 | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/source/git/git_proxy.rb:155:in `allowed_in_path': The git source git://github.com/guard/guard-test.git is not yet checked out. Please run `bundle install` before trying to start your application (Bundler::GitError)
sidekiq_1 |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/source/git/git_proxy.rb:47:in `revision'
sidekiq_1 |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/source/git.rb:215:in `revision'
sidekiq_1 |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/source/git.rb:85:in `install_path'
sidekiq_1 |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/source/path.rb:110:in `expanded_path'
sidekiq_1 |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/source/path.rb:132:in `load_spec_files'
sidekiq_1 |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/source/git.rb:188:in `load_spec_files'
sidekiq_1 |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/source/path.rb:92:in `local_specs'
sidekiq_1 |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/source/git.rb:159:in `specs'
sidekiq_1 |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:550:in `block in converge_locked_specs'
sidekiq_1 |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:539:in `each'
sidekiq_1 |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:539:in `converge_locked_specs'
sidekiq_1 |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:195:in `resolve'
sidekiq_1 |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:140:in `specs'
sidekiq_1 |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:185:in `specs_for'
sidekiq_1 |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:174:in `requested_specs'
sidekiq_1 |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
sidekiq_1 |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
sidekiq_1 |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:127:in `setup'
sidekiq_1 |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
sidekiq_1 |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
sidekiq_1 |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
web_1     | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/source/git/git_proxy.rb:155:in `allowed_in_path': The git source git://github.com/guard/guard-test.git is not yet checked out. Please run `bundle install` before trying to start your application (Bundler::GitError)
web_1     |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/source/git/git_proxy.rb:47:in `revision'
web_1     |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/source/git.rb:215:in `revision'
web_1     |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/source/git.rb:85:in `install_path'
web_1     |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/source/path.rb:110:in `expanded_path'
web_1     |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/source/path.rb:132:in `load_spec_files'
web_1     |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/source/git.rb:188:in `load_spec_files'
web_1     |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/source/path.rb:92:in `local_specs'
web_1     |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/source/git.rb:159:in `specs'
web_1     |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:550:in `block in converge_locked_specs'
web_1     |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:539:in `each'
web_1     |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:539:in `converge_locked_specs'
web_1     |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:195:in `resolve'
web_1     |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:140:in `specs'
web_1     |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:185:in `specs_for'
web_1     |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:174:in `requested_specs'
web_1     |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
web_1     |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
web_1     |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:127:in `setup'
web_1     |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
web_1     |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
web_1     |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
testapp_sidekiq_1 exited with code 1
testapp_web_1 exited with code 1
```

What's meaning about that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `bundle install` in your Docker container.

Comment: Yes. I did that. But this one is not okay: git://github.com/guard/guard-test.git