# Can't start Rails application (invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8

I am having issues starting my rails application. I run `rails s`, I get the following error:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 5.0.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
    14: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
    13: from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    12: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    11: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    10: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
     9: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
     8: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `block in server'
     7: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:77:in `start'
     6: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:124:in `log_to_stdout'
     5: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
     4: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:59:in `app'
     3: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
     2: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
     1: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:36:in `parse_file'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:36:in `[]': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
```

I don't know what is going on and why it's happening. I have searched all online for a solution. Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Is there anything weird in `bin/rails`? Any non-UTF8 characters?

Comment: Try this gem https://github.com/whitequark/rack-utf8_sanitizer/

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839674/bundle-install-error-invalid-byte-sequence-in-us-ascii-argumenterror